# Itunes connect can't upload large app icon

Tags: ios, icons, app-store-connect

I have everything else ready submitting app for review but the large app icon (1024x1024) is not working. I have tried:

1024x1024 jpeg
1024x1024 png
1024x1024 tiff
512x512 jpg

I have done and redone these images from original, checked and rechecked and can't find anything wrong. Also the error message I get is bit wonky. When trying to submit the icon, it loads it for maybe 10 secs and then errors:

"One or more screenshots aren't in the RGB color space."

I have submitted screenshots from all different screensize versions per instructions and they uploaded with no problems.

Scanned the site and net for answers but the specific error I'm getting is not found. Lots of problems related to large app icon uploading though but those I have mostly tried already.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How did you generate the app icon and the screenshots? (i.e. what software did you use, how did you export the images you uploaded, etc.?) If you take iTunes Connect at its word, one or more of your files isn't in the RGB colour space. Graphics files of various kinds can have different associated colour spaces (RGB, CMYK, etc.); these can be set when, for example, exporting from Photoshop. If the error isn't bogus, you need to figure out whether your screenshots may have been exported with a non-RGB colour space.

Comment: (Thinking about it, and knowing iTunes Connect, it feels likely to me that it might be complaining about an alpha channel being present, i.e. you may have a PNG file in RGBA mode rather than just plain RGB.)

Comment: The error can be misleading to verify Just create a black 1024X1024px graphics with minumum 72dpi without alpha channel and try to upload to see if you are getting same error.

Comment: The icons are old products made by an outsider, most likely with Photoshop. I have several different versions of them, gift, tiff, jpg, png and so fort. These were simply scaled to fit the size with Mac Preview. The screenshots are just simply Xcode iOS simulator screenshots that have been cropped and made to fit the size with Mac Preview again. iTunes connect is down at the moment, will test plain black screen when it goes up again.

Comment: Problem solved: tried first basic black screen 1024x1024 in png format to large icon, made with Paintbrush. Didn't work, problem with alpha. I then ran it through preview and removed alpha, then no problem. I dug up an even older version of the icon that I then ran through preview and removed alpha, that worked. Apparently the first icon I tried had some colour space associations that messed up the upload.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: tried first basic black screen 1024x1024 in png format to large icon, made with Paintbrush. Didn't work, problem with alpha. I then ran it through preview and removed alpha, then no problem. I dug up an even older version of the icon that I then ran through preview and removed alpha, that worked. Apparently the first icon I tried had some colour space associations that messed up the upload. –